# Google Cloud - ChronoSync - Data

Tags: google-cloud-platform

A few months back ChronoSync stopped connecting to my Google Cloud Account - I think there was a Google Cloud update, I did not implement it - pandemic problems.
Now I am getting things back in order. I have onsite backup, and this is not a data emergency.
But where are my several near-line projects? I see only a "My First Project"...
I will add that I have been getting billed as if data were being stored...
Any explanations for what I am experiencing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest contacting [Cloud Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) directly. This does not seem to be a [question](https://serverfault.com/help/dont-ask) fit to be in this site, as it is not [on topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). GCP Billing support should be able to take a look at your project and let you know exactly what you are being charged for.